# Array map with an array of callbacks

Tags: arrays, typescript, callback

If I have an array of callbacks i can call them all like so

```
const callbacks = [
  (string) => string,
  (string) => string,
  (string) => string
];

for (let callback of callbacks) {
  callback('some value')
}
```

How can I instead use Array map instead of the for loop to pass `some value` to each of the array's elements as an argument?

```
callbacks.map(?)
```

Comment: You want to do the equivalent of `callback[2](callback[1](callback[0](value)))` right? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: What's your expected output? What do you want to achieve by using `map`?

Comment: `callbacks.map(cb => cb('some value'))`

Comment: Should use `forEach` instead of map: `callbacks.forEach(callback => callback('some value'));`

Comment: Fair suggestion, but I don't want to mutate the original array

Comment: I agree with HTN - you should use forEach for this. You use map when you want to modify the contents of the array.

`callbacks.forEach(cb => cb("some value"))`

Comment: I'm quite confused now, I thought `forEach` is mutable which modifies the contents of the array while `map` is immutable by returning a new array?

Comment: @myol both are "mutable". Both have access to the objects in the array and you can perform mutation in either case. With that said, if you give a pure function as callback, both would perform a pure operation. Neither will try to change the underlying array by themselves. It all depends on the callback.